# regex for special character

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode

If you think you should block me from asking questions, you are welcome.

I have a pdf file which I run pdf2txt on and I cleaned it using regex. However, occasionally there is one line that puzzles me and which defies to get regexed. It looks like this:

123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233341234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333439

Between numbers 34 and 39 (end of the line) there is a square box with two zeros in the upper line and a zero and C in the lower line. It is NOT shown in my question here, so I guess as a control character it means sth like "zero space". I did not find this kind of character here: [jrgraphix.net](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2400-243F) or other unicode collections.

I copied the control character and put it here: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) and it resolved into a red bullet. Here: https: //regex101.com/ (my "reputation" only allows for 2 links), it resolved into a black bullet. I do not find a red or black bullet in the original PDF file.

I also tried to get rid of this line with code like this (Python 3):

```
    if '123456789' in line:
        print('found this line')
```

... which did not find this line.

My regex expressions so far are:

```
    line = re.sub(r'\u25a0', '', line)
    line = re.sub(r'\u2022', '', line)
    line = re.sub(r'\u200B', '', line)
    line = re.sub(r'\u200b', '', line)
```

My Python code dealing with white space:

```
    elif re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
        pass
```

Can you help me how I can make either regex or Python find that character?

Comment: It is a form feed char. See https://ideone.com/VGzqXu

Comment: You need no regex to remove a form feed char, just use `.replace("\f", "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex for finding a form feed is `\f`, however, if you want to weed out unknown characters, perhaps you may want to just define what is allowed, rather than trying to figure out all the possible things that are not..

Comment: When I cat the text on bash the character is resolved to ^L ... when I use \f I can capture the red dot on RegExr or regex101, but it doesn't work in my code. I guess I stick with your advice to define what characters are allowed, saves me a lot of headaches.